# How to read Geographical data programatically using c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, gis

I want to read Geographical data(i.e. Public IP, Latitude, Longitude, ZipCode etc...) of machine for almost all windows desktop/server version.

Is there any win32 API's to read these above data programmatically.

I have tried Sensor API's in windows 10, getting error (" fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sensorsapi.h': No such file or directory"), Is there any updates required to get required headers and binaries.
and also it supports only desktop version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sensorsapi/nn-sensorsapi-isensor

Can you please help with the different standard ways I can read Geo details of the windows OS using C++?

Answer (score 0):

You did not say way you do not want the desktop version if using c++. Anyway, you can use the [Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation) namespace.

Example project [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation).

For desktop-only, you can use [ILocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/locationapi/nn-locationapi-ilocation). The [Sensor API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sensorsapi/nn-sensorsapi-isensormanager) also works, check correct SDK/VS toolset configuration.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply, Geolocation need location permission enabled to get data, I want to know which technology I can use to get GeoLoaction without any permission, Ex "https://www.whatismyip.net/" by hitting URL

Comment: Sensor API sample code always return "No Data", May this application required permission to read the location!

Comment: For desktop apps, you don't need any extra permissions. Getting the location from IP based services is something entirely different.